# Pandas read csv, always get 1 column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Edit: To note as well I have already searched for this problem, but nothing has worked for me.

First line of data, 109 different fields for one line:

> 15/12/2022,13:53:27,Off,0,0.00,19.9,22.6,19.6,1,Normal,Operator,Not Fitted,14,83:04:21,34:23:28,28:04:51,0,0,0,3025,0,3551,3535,3446,240,0,239,0,0,Not Fitted,125.11:37:20,44.23:11:47,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,21,2,0,0,21.8,0.0,0.0,23.2,21,26,34,1,66,133,8,60,5,74.16:01:01,23.02:02:40,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,25,2.8,0,0,21.4,0.0,0.0,22.2,21,24.1,32,2,64,133,8,28,1,122.22:39:33,43.18:38:50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,1.6,0,0,21.4,0.0,0.0,22.5,21.2,24.1,32,2,64,133,8,28,1,No Alarms

So, in this case its comma delimited. But when I try

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=',', error_bad_lines=False, engine='python')
```

Or even using different combinations I always get one column out.

```
           16:02:29 On          4554  0.00   23.5             36.8                   21.1                    1                    Normal                    Operator     Not Fitted      14             83:06:30                  35:01:19                 28:06:27                 0    0                 0                 3025              0                 3502         3413         2911         245        0       1579       0              0                Not Fitted       125.13:45:20     45.01:01:51        98                   4025                         98.3                       96              2627                    0               0                       12                4.4                0                  0                      27                            0.0                           0.0                   39.1                       24.4                             39.6                         51                0                 67                     133                    9                      124                    5                      74.18:09:01      23.03:52:44        98                   4018                         98.1                       100             2746                    0               0                       17                5.5                0                  0                      25.1                          0.0                           0.0                   32.3                       23.6                             34.6                         51                0                 67                     133                    9                      124                    5                      123.00:47:33     43.20:28:54        97                   4003                         97.8                       101             2767                    0               0                       16                4.6                0                  0                      25.4                          0.0                           0.0                   32.2                       23.9                             34.1                         51                0                 67                     133                    9                      124                    5                                                       No Alarms Present                                                                                                 

[3944 rows x 1 columns]
```

Its meant to have about 70+ columns but whatever I do I get the same result.

I am trying to use Pandas to incorporate it into another program which uses it as well.

The library is also up to data along with python.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have columm identifiers/headers? Can't see any from your example

Comment: Please, fix the sample input (properly formatted), so that it is clear where lines end. Is this one or multiple lines? These are 109 fields if split at `,`. Also, did you check that e.g. lines are not enclosed in quotes?

Comment: @nordmanden, I do have headers I just can't add them. It doesn't matter whether they are included in the data or not

Comment: @buran Question updated, did not know how to show that really. What do you mean by enclosed in quotes?

Comment: I mean, check that when creating the file it was not malformed by adding quotes at the start and at the end of line, i.e. making the whole line one field that contains sep values, thus in need to be quoted

Comment: @JoshM i'm not asking for your literal headers, I'm asking for the top of the file, where you typically have headers. The issue comes from your input, so let us see your input.

Comment: So this is just a single line, and it has 109 fields (i.e. down the question you mention 70+. 109 is indeed 70+, but 70+ is something that implies (more or less no more than 80)

Comment: Buy the way, the sample output doesn't suggest  comma-separated values, rather tab-separated or fixed-width

Comment: Are you sure your separator is `,` and not a similar unicode character like `，`. What is the output of `[ord(c) for c in open('data.csv', 'rb').read(30).decode()]`?

Comment: @nordmanden Thanks for the direction, there was an error in this particular file which caused the issue. By removing the headers it reads normally and after fixing the file it now works